# At what level of the analytic hierarchy do Cohen reals lie?

Tags: set-theory, forcing, descriptive-set-theory, ordinal-computability

In his doctoral thesis titled "Three models of ordinal computability", Benjamin Seyfferth proved the following theorems:

i) A set $\mathtt A$ of reals is Ordinal Turing Machine-enumerable if and only if it is $\Sigma^{1}_2$

ii) A set $\mathtt A$ of reals is Ordinal Turing Machine-computable if and only if it is $\Delta^{1}_2$

In either case (by the fact that $\mathtt A$ should be able to be OTM-computable or enumerable without parameters or from a finite number of parameters), $\mathtt A$$\in$$\mathtt L$.

Now form the model $\mathtt L$[$\mathtt c$] where $\mathtt c$ is a Cohen real.  By a theorem  Prof. Hamkins proved in his answer to Mohammad Golshani's MathOverflow question "Reals added after Cohen forcing" (question 99013), $\mathtt L$[$\mathtt c$] has a perfect set $\mathtt P$ "all of whose finite subsets are mutually $\mathtt L$-generic Cohen reals".

I have several questions regarding $\mathtt P$.

i)  Where does $\mathtt P$ lie in the (lightface) Analytic hierarchy.

ii)  are all of the Cohen reals in $\mathtt P$ at the same level of the Analytic hierarchy and if so, what is that level?

iii) can $\mathtt P$ be defined in terms of OTM-computability or OTM-enumerability, even though $\mathtt P$ is neither OTM-computable nor OTM-enumerable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had asked about the perfect set $P$, but before treating that, let me first explain what is the complexity of the set of all $L$-generic Cohen reals:

**Theorem.** The set of reals that are $L$-generic for Cohen
forcing is defined by a $\Pi^1_2$ definition. If non-empty, it is
not defined by any $\Sigma^1_2$ definition. Hence in this case it
is not $\Delta^1_2$.

Proof. Let $C$ be the set of $L$-generic Cohen reals. That is,
$x\in C$ just in case $x\in 2^\omega$ and whenever $D\subset
2^{<\omega}$ is dense in this partial order and $D\in L$, then
some initial segment of $x$ is in $D$. That is, $$x\in C\iff
\forall D\left[(D\in L\text{ and }D\subset 2^{<\omega}\text{ is
dense})\to\exists n\ (x\upharpoonright n)\in D\right].$$ This
definition has complexity $\Pi^1_2$, because there is the
universal quantifier $\forall D$ in front, which is quantifying
over reals, and the statement $D\in L$ has complexity
$\Sigma^1_2$, since $D\in L$ just in case there is a real coding a
well-founded relation isomorphic to some $L_\alpha$ with $D\in
L_\alpha$. The rest of the assertions inside the square braces are
simple, and because $D\in L$ is on the hypothesis of the
implication, it makes the whole implication inside the square
braces have complexity $\Pi^1_2$, making the whole assertion
$\Pi^1_2$.

Meanwhile, for the second claim, if $C$ is not empty, then the
assertion $\exists x\ x\in C$ is true in $V$, but it cannot be
true in $L$, since there are no $L$-generic Cohen reals in $L$,
and so in this case $x\in C$ cannot be $\Sigma^1_2$ expressible,
or it would be absolute to $L$ by Shoenfield absoluteness. QED

Now, about your questions concerning the perfect set $P$ from the other question. Since every branch through $P$ is an $L$-generic Cohen real, I claim that no such $P$ can be definable in $L[c]$ without parameters. The reason is that if $P$ were definable, then the left-most branch $d$ through $P$ would also be definable, and so in $L[c]$ we will have defined the $L$-generic Cohen real $d$ without parameters. But this is impossible, since on homogeneity grounds, every hereditarily definable set in $L[c]$ is contained in $L$. So $P$ does not occur at all in the lightface hierarchy, and also none of its members occur there.

Comment: @Prof. Hamkins:  Your answer is very helpful in clarifying the situation.  Now I will have to think about what questions one can properly ask about $\mathtt P$ in light of your clarification (and that's a very good thing indeed....).  Thank you.

Comment: I edited to add the observation that no nonempty closed set $P$ of Cohen reals can be definable in $L[c]$, since if it were, then the left-most member of $P$ would be a definable Cohen real in $L[c]$, and this is impossible.

Comment: @Prof Hamkins.  This is very helpful indeed.

Comment: @Prof. Hamkins:  You seem to raise the possibility that $\mathtt P$ can be defined in $\mathtt L$[$\mathtt c$] with parameters.  If this is a correct inference then what parameters would these be?  If not, let me know that, too.

Comment: Well, $P$ is obviously definable using parameter $P$ itself....

Comment: Well yes, but was that the only parameter[s] you were referring to?

Comment: The $P$ I defined in the other answer was defined from the fixed Cohen real $c$; that may be more satisfactory. But actually, they are definable from each other, since from $P$ I believe that one can define $c$.